# Is this possible to list available alphabet of the current locale in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

Is this possible to list available alphanet of the current locale in GWT?

Comment: An idea is to define all possible alphabets in a Constants implenentation, but I want to know if there is more easier ways.

    @DefaultStringArrayValue("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z")
String[] alphabet();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to define all possible alphabets in a Constants implementation:

```
@DefaultStringArrayValue("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z")
String[] alphabet();
```